# Can not open Setting in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-settings-daemon

Could you please show me how to open Setting App in ubuntu 18.04?

I already try below command:

```
  sudo apt-get remove gnome-control-center
  sudo apt autoremove
  sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

but after that, when I tried to run cmd:

```
gnome-control-center
```

this is output

> ```
> nome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
> gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined 
> symbol:gst_state_change_get_name
> ```

UPDATE:
this is output of: ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37

> linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff907e9000)
>       libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f70be722000)
>       libEGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1 (0x00007f70be50e000)
>       librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f70be306000)
>       libgtk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007f70bd9fe000)
>       libgdk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007f70bd708000)
>       libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f70bd4bb000)
>       libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f70bd295000)
>       libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f70bcf78000)
>       libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f70bcd54000)
>       libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f70bc9b5000)
>       libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f70bc761000)
>       libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f70bc44b000)
>       libnotify.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4 (0x00007f70bc243000)
>       libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f70bbe82000)
>       libxslt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1 (0x00007f70bbc45000)
>       libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f70bb93c000)
>       libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18 (0x00007f70ba6c1000)
>       libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f70ba4bd000)
>       libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60 (0x00007f70ba106000)
>       libicui18n.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.60 (0x00007f70b9c65000)
>       libwoff2dec.so.1.0.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwoff2dec.so.1.0.2 (0x00007f70b9a5a000)
>       libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f70b9815000)
>       libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f70b9561000)
>       libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f70b92c3000)
>       libharfbuzz-icu.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz-icu.so.0 (0x00007f70b90c0000)
>       libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f70b8da5000)
>       libgstapp-1.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgstapp-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f70b8b98000)
>       libgstbase-1.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f70b8935000)
>       libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f70b860d000)
>       libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f70b83d9000)
>       libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f70b8182000)
>       libgsttag-1.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgsttag-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f70b7f48000)
>       libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f70b7cd6000)
>       libgstgl-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstgl-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f70b7a70000)
>       libgstfft-1.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgstfft-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f70b7865000)
>       libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f70b75fd000)
>       libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f70b73cb000)
>       libwebp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6 (0x00007f70b7162000)
>       libwebpdemux.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebpdemux.so.2 (0x00007f70b6f5d000)
>       libenchant.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libenchant.so.1 (0x00007f70b6d51000)
>       libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f70b6b4d000)
>       libsecret-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsecret-1.so.0 (0x00007f70b68fd000)
>       libsoup-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoup-2.4.so.1 (0x00007f70b660a000)
>       libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f70b63f7000)
>       libhyphen.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhyphen.so.0 (0x00007f70b61f1000)
>       libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f70b5eb9000)
>       libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f70b5cb6000)
>       libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f70b5ab3000)
>       libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f70b5896000)
>       libwayland-server.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-server.so.0 (0x00007f70b5683000)
>       libwayland-egl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007f70b5481000)
>       libwayland-client.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f70b5272000)
>       libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f70b4ee9000)
>       libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f70b4b4b000)
>       libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f70b4933000)
>       libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f70b4714000)
>       libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f70b4323000)
>       /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f70c14e3000)
>       libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f70b40f2000)
>       libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f70b3e3c000)
>       libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f70b3c2f000)
>       libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f70b3a1f000)
>       libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f70b3819000)
>       libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007f70b3610000)
>       libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f70b33df000)
>       libepoxy.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0 (0x00007f70b30de000)
>       libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f70b2ec8000)
>       libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f70b2cc5000)
>       libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f70b2aba000)
>       libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f70b28b0000)
>       libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f70b2671000)
>       libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007f70b2469000)
>       libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f70b2257000)
>       libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f70b204e000)
>       libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f70b1da9000)
>       libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f70b1ba6000)
>       libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f70b197e000)
>       libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f70b1771000)
>       libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f70b1567000)
>       libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f70b133f000)
>       libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f70b1124000)
>       libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f70b0ed0000)
>       libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f70b0cc8000)
>       libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f70b0a56000)
>       liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f70b0830000)
>       libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60 (0x00007f70aec87000)
>       libwoff2common.so.1.0.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwoff2common.so.1.0.2 (0x00007f70aea84000)
>       libbrotlidec.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007f70ae878000)
>       libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f70ae646000)
>       libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f70ae419000)
>       libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f70ae204000)
>       libgstallocators-1.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgstallocators-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f70ae000000)
>       libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f70addfe000)
>       libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f70adbed000)
>       libgbm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 (0x00007f70ad9df000)
>       libgudev-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgudev-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f70ad7d5000)
>       libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f70ad58a000)
>       libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f70ad33d000)
>       libatspi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0 (0x00007f70ad10d000)
>       libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f70acf06000)
>       libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f70acd02000)
>       libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f70acafc000)
>       libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f70ac8af000)
>       libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007f70ac68f000)
>       libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f70ac471000)
>       libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f70ac19b000)
>       libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f70abf69000)
>       libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f70abd65000)
>       libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f70abb5a000)
>       libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f70ab8d6000)
>       libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f70ab6c1000)
>       libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f70ab4ba000)
>       libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f70ab2b6000)
>       liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f70ab09a000)

and this is output of: dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37

> libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please add output of `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37` and `dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with the library itself. Please try this and let me know if it helps.

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
sudo apt-get install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2
```

Comment: Hello, Thank for your support but after the above commands, I still got the same output. :( It seems It does not work.